# Rasa x server keep restarting in Centos 8.2

Tags: docker, docker-compose, centos, rasa

I want to deploy rasa-x on my linux machine. I have used docker-compose to deploy:
Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.4"

x-database-credentials: &database-credentials
  DB_HOST: "db"
  DB_PORT: "5432"
  DB_USER: "${DB_USER:-admin}"
  DB_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
  DB_LOGIN_DB: "${DB_LOGIN_DB:-rasa}"

x-rabbitmq-credentials: &rabbitmq-credentials
  RABBITMQ_HOST: "rabbit"
  RABBITMQ_USERNAME: "user"
  RABBITMQ_PASSWORD: ${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}

x-redis-credentials: &redis-credentials
  REDIS_HOST: "redis"
  REDIS_PORT: "6379"
  REDIS_PASSWORD: ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
  REDIS_DB: "1"

x-duckling-credentials: &duckling-credentials
  RASA_DUCKLING_HTTP_URL: "http://duckling:8000"

x-rasax-credentials: &rasax-credentials
  RASA_X_HOST: "http://rasa-x:5006"
  RASA_X_USERNAME: ${RASA_X_USERNAME:-admin}
  RASA_X_PASSWORD: ${RASA_X_PASSWORD:-}
  RASA_X_TOKEN: ${RASA_X_TOKEN}
  JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}
  RASA_USER_APP: "http://app:5056"
  RASA_PRODUCTION_HOST: "http://rasa-production:5006"
  RASA_WORKER_HOST: "http://rasa-worker:5006"
  RASA_TOKEN: ${RASA_TOKEN}

x-rasa-credentials: &rasa-credentials
  <<: *rabbitmq-credentials
  <<: *rasax-credentials
  <<: *database-credentials
  <<: *redis-credentials
  <<: *duckling-credentials
  RASA_TOKEN: ${RASA_TOKEN}
  RASA_MODEL_PULL_INTERVAL: 10
  RABBITMQ_QUEUE: "rasa_production_events"

x-rasa-services: &default-rasa-service
  restart: always
  image: "rasa/rasa:${RASA_VERSION}-full"
  expose:
    - "5006"
  command: >
    x
    --no-prompt
    --production
    --config-endpoint http://rasa-x:5006/api/config?token=${RASA_X_TOKEN}
    --port 5006
    --jwt-method HS256
    --jwt-secret ${JWT_SECRET}
    --auth-token '${RASA_TOKEN}'
    --cors "*"
  depends_on:
    - rasa-x
    - rabbit
    - redis

services:
  rasa-x:
    restart: on-failure
    image: "rasa/rasa-x:${RASA_X_VERSION}"
    ports:
      - "5006:5006"
    volumes:
      - ./models:/app/models
      - ./environments.yml:/app/environments.yml
      - ./credentials.yml:/app/credentials.yml
      - ./endpoints.yml:/app/endpoints.yml
      - ./logs:/logs
      - ./auth:/app/auth
    environment:
      <<: *database-credentials
      <<: *rasa-credentials
      SELF_PORT: "5006"
      DB_DATABASE: "${DB_DATABASE:-rasa}"
      RASA_MODEL_DIR: "/app/models"
      PASSWORD_SALT: ${PASSWORD_SALT}
      RABBITMQ_QUEUE: "rasa_production_events"
      RASA_X_USER_ANALYTICS: "0"
      SANIC_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT: "3600"
    depends_on:
      - db

  rasa-production:
    <<: *default-rasa-service
    environment:
      <<: *rasa-credentials
      RASA_ENVIRONMENT: "production"
      DB_DATABASE: "tracker"
      RASA_MODEL_SERVER: "http://rasa-x:5006/api/projects/default/models/tags/production"

  rasa-worker:
    <<: *default-rasa-service
    environment:
      <<: *rasa-credentials
      RASA_ENVIRONMENT: "worker"
      DB_DATABASE: "worker_tracker"
      RASA_MODEL_SERVER: "http://rasa-x:5006/api/projects/default/models/tags/production"

  app:
    restart: always
    image: "rasa/rasa-x-demo:${RASA_X_DEMO_VERSION}"
    expose:
      - "5056"
    depends_on:
      - rasa-production

  db:
    restart: on-failure
    image: "bitnami/postgresql:11.7.0"
    user: '1005'
    expose:
      - "5432"   
    environment:
      POSTGRESQL_USERNAME: "${DB_USER:-admin}"
      POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
      POSTGRESQL_DATABASE: "${DB_DATABASE:-rasa}"
    volumes:
      - ./db:/bitnami/postgresql

  rabbit:
    restart: always
    image: "bitnami/rabbitmq:3.8.3"
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_HOST: "rabbit"
      RABBITMQ_USERNAME: "user"
      RABBITMQ_PASSWORD: ${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}
      RABBITMQ_DISK_FREE_LIMIT: "{mem_relative, 0.1}"
    expose:
      - "5672"

  duckling:
    restart: always
    image: "rasa/duckling:0.1.6.3"
    expose:
      - "8000"
    command: ["duckling-example-exe", "--no-access-log", "--no-error-log"]

  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: "rasa/nginx:${RASA_X_VERSION}"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "443:8443"
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/opt/bitnami/certs
      - ./terms:/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/terms
    depends_on:
      - rasa-x
      - rasa-production
      - app

  redis:
    restart: always
    image: "bitnami/redis:5.0.8"
    environment:
      REDIS_PASSWORD: ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
    expose:
      - "6379"
```

This is the logs of db:

```
             | postgresql 12:36:50.30 Welcome to the Bitnami postgresql container
db_1               | postgresql 12:36:50.30 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql
db_1               | postgresql 12:36:50.31 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql/issues
db_1               | postgresql 12:36:50.31 
db_1               | postgresql 12:36:50.85 INFO  ==> ** Starting PostgreSQL setup **
db_1               | postgresql 12:36:51.75 INFO  ==> Validating settings in POSTGRESQL_* env vars..
db_1               | postgresql 12:36:51.76 INFO  ==> Loading custom pre-init scripts...
db_1               | postgresql 12:36:51.99 INFO  ==> Initializing PostgreSQL database...
db_1               | postgresql 12:36:52.37 INFO  ==> postgresql.conf file not detected. Generating it...
db_1               | postgresql 12:36:52.55 INFO  ==> pg_hba.conf file not detected. Generating it...
db_1               | postgresql 12:36:52.60 INFO  ==> Generating local authentication configuration
db_1               | postgresql 12:37:13.50 INFO  ==> Starting PostgreSQL in background...
db_1               | postgresql 12:37:17.77 INFO  ==> Creating user admin
db_1               | postgresql 12:37:17.87 INFO  ==> Granting access to "admin" to the database "rasa"
db_1               | postgresql 12:37:18.25 INFO  ==> Configuring replication parameters
db_1               | postgresql 12:37:18.43 INFO  ==> Configuring fsync
db_1               | postgresql 12:37:18.49 INFO  ==> Loading custom scripts...
db_1               | postgresql 12:37:18.53 INFO  ==> Enabling remote connections
db_1               | postgresql 12:37:18.62 INFO  ==> Stopping PostgreSQL...
db_1               | postgresql 12:37:19.87 INFO  ==> ** PostgreSQL setup finished! **
db_1               | 
db_1               | postgresql 12:37:22.12 INFO  ==> ** Starting PostgreSQL **
db_1               | 2020-09-03 12:37:22.716 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1               | 2020-09-03 12:37:22.717 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1               | 2020-09-03 12:37:22.733 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1               | 2020-09-03 12:37:22.805 GMT [211] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-09-03 12:37:18 GMT
db_1               | 2020-09-03 12:37:22.828 GMT [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

- The db is connected

This is the logs of rasa-x:

```
asa-x_1           | Traceback (most recent call last):
rasa-x_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2339, in _wrap_pool_connect
rasa-x_1           |     return fn()
rasa-x_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 304, in unique_connection
rasa-x_1           |     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
rasa-x_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 778, in _checkout
rasa-x_1           |     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
rasa-x_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 495, in checkout
rasa-x_1           |     rec = pool._do_get()
rasa-x_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 140, in _do_get
rasa-x_1           |     self._dec_overflow()
rasa-x_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
rasa-x_1           |     exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
rasa-x_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
rasa-x_1           |     raise exception
rasa-x_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 137, in _do_get
rasa-x_1           |     return self._create_connection()
rasa-x_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 309, in _create_connection
rasa-x_1           |     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
rasa-x_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 440, in __init__
rasa-x_1           |     self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
rasa-x_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in __connect
rasa-x_1           |     pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
rasa-x_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
rasa-x_1           |     exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
rasa-x_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
rasa-x_1           |     raise exception
rasa-x_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 656, in __connect
rasa-x_1           |     connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
rasa-x_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
rasa-x_1           |     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
rasa-x_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 493, in connect
rasa-x_1           |     return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
rasa-x_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
rasa-x_1           |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
rasa-x_1           | psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No route to host
rasa-x_1           |    Is the server running on host "db" (172.18.0.5) and accepting
rasa-x_1           |    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
rasa-x_1           |
```

Any help would be very very appreciated.
Rasa x server keep restarting, I dont know the exact issues.
I am using CentOS 8 as If i run this docker-compose on windows it run fine.

Comment: Which version of docker, docker-compose do you have installed on CentOS 8? Did you try to update it if it's not the latest one?